# Rails, polymorphic association - find records with non-dead associated records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have following Comments-on-Models design (source: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association):

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Post
  has_many :comments, as => :commentable
end

class Message
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

etc...
```

How can I select all records from 'comments' table, so that each record has non-dead commentable (dead means original fx Post was deleted) by scope-based query?

Comment: It is still actual! I want to avoid the obvious use of opposite strategy - cleaning up associated records (in join table) when commentable is deleted by after_destroy callbacks.

Comment: It is not actual now, but is still very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Since `commentable` not exists in case of dead-commentable, you can do something like this:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  scope :non_dead_commentable, where('commentable IS NOT NULL')
end
```

In rails 4 you can do:

```
scope :non_dead_commentable, where.not(:commentable => nil)
```

And then:

```
Comment.non_dead_commentable
```